# Kernel.loop method requires 'do' . Semicolon not allowed?

Tags: ruby, syntax, loops, kernel

With certain constructs, I have the choice of using a semicolon or the `do` keyword to delimit the end of a statement, as with the `until` example below.

```
until x == 100 do puts x; x+=1 end 

until x == 100; puts x; x+=1 end
```

But this is not possible with `Kernel.loop`.

```
x=0    
loop do puts x; x+=1; break if x == 100 end

x=0    
loop; puts x; x+=1; break if x == 100 end # => error
```

Is there a reason why it's like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `loop` is a method (in `Kernel`) that really requires a block with `do...end` or `{ }`.
- `while` and `until` are statements (like `if`), and do not expect a block.  The `do` keyword is optional, but it does not denote a block (e.g. `while x == 100 { puts x; x+=1; }` will fail miserably, whereas `loop { puts x; x+=1; break if x == 100 }` will work just fine.)

So, `do` means different things in the two cases.  In the case of `loop` (and other methods) it really denotes a block; in the case of `while`, `until` etc. it is just syntactic sugar (just like `then` is after `if`.)  Do not be misled.